# How can I run a Java program passing a command line argument to a method?

Tags: java, jar

I have a `Java` class named `Client` with `main(String[] args)`.

`main` uses classes defined in a `jar` called `lib.jar`. How can I run the program from the command line passing command line argument to `main`?

I tried:

```
java -cp lib.jar Client arg1 arg2
```

**and got this error:**

`Error: Could not find or load main class Client`

Comment: Is it `main()` or is it `main(String[] args)`?

Comment: "it did not work" is *never* enough information. What you've shown is indeed how you pass command line arguments. So what happened? If you got a class loading exception, then perhaps you wanted `java -cp lib.jar;.` (Windows) or `java -cp lib.jar:.` (Unix) so that the current directory is on the classpath as well? Without knowing what happened, we have no way of helping you - we're just guessing.

Comment: @childofsoong `main(String[] args)`

Comment: In future, please get all the relevant information *before* you ask a question, ideally posting a [mcve]. Please bear in mind that the aim of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of high quality questions and answers. Without enough information, this is not a high quality question.

Comment: Is the main class `Client` or is it something more like `com.example.www.SomePackage.Client`, perhaps?

Comment: OK, I have edited the question, no need to down vote any more. Thank you.

Comment: @childofsoong the method main is in a class that is in the default package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: @JonSkeet I have edited my question to the best of my ability. This problem is driving me crazy, any help?

Comment: Right, it's a classpath problem, as I suggested in my second comment. Your classpath currently *only* consists of `lib.jar`, which doesn't contain `Client`.

Comment: Note that you should also read the [mcve] page for how to *really* provide a minimal but complete example.

Answer (score 0):

java -jar fileName.jar arg1 arg2

Assuming you exported the project as a .jar.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(args[0]);
}
```

Make sure you do the main method correct, as well.

Answer (score -1):

java -cp lib.jar packageName.className arg1 arg2

Comment: @AbAppletic: Well it is, because we don't know whether the problem is that you didn't package-qualify the class name. This is the sort of thing that posting a [mcve] would help to avoid. Without enough information, you're just inviting other people's to waste time guessing.

Comment: @AbAppletic, Yes you didn't specify in the question that you have specified the package name or not.